# Android's spinner automatic scrolling when text is too long

Tags: android, scroll, spinner, horizontal-scrolling

In my layout there is a spinner (drop-down list) with fixed width, some entries are longer than the spinner so I want them to automatically scroll horizontally when chosen.

I know you can apply automatic horizontal scroll to textview like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" />
```

I tried to apply same settings to my spinner as follows:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

But it doesn't scroll. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spinner extends **AdapterView** which is backed by an Adapter class.

So much like you can customise each row in a ListView, you should be able to do the same for your Spinner by overriding a method like **Adapter.getView()**.

There you could return a simple TextView with the **ellipsize** property.

Hope it helps you a lot.